# Rearrange multiple lists with a loop

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

Hey I'm just trying to put the last 1000 in a few numbpy arrays to the front. However I am getting the following value error:

```
  File "C:script.py", line 102, in <module>
data = np.array(temp)
```

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

The can someone explain why this is not working. I apologize if this question has been answered somewhere else but I couldn't find it anywhere. Here is the code:

```
NSTEPx = np.array(NSTEPx)
TIMEx = np.array(TIMEx)
TEMPx = np.array(TEMPx)
PRESSx = np.array(PRESSx)
Etotx = np.array(Etotx)
EKtotx = np.array(EKtotx)
EPtotx = np.array(EPtotx)
VOLUMEx = np.array(VOLUMEx)
alldata = [NSTEPx,TIMEx,TEMPx, PRESSx, Etotx, EKtotx, EPtotx]
for data in alldata:
    temp = list(data[1001:-1])
    temp.append(list(data[0:1000]))
    data = np.array(temp)e
```

Comment: Instead use the `numpy.insert` function, it is built for this. I.e. 1) extract the elements, 2) delete the elements from where you took them, 3) put them in front.

Comment: And, you could use `numpy.asarray` which only does copy if it is not already an array, this is more sensible for large amounts of data.